# Centering divs in CSS - how does this work?

Tags: html, css

I can't understand how this works and why it centers. Why is it **width: 70%;** and not 50% / 25%?

I cannot get my head around this. I'm just trying to learn the basics on web dev. I'm completely stumpted.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.top-header {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-header">
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`width: 70%` is just an option, it very well can be 50% or 25%. It doesn't matter. What matters is having a `width` when you use `margin: auto`. Setting the margin to auto will auto-calculate  the distant of the element from its container and adjust the element in the center accordingly

Answer (score 0):

setting elements to the centre in CSS, like div here we use the attribute `margin: auto;`
 the width only ensures that it doesn't take the whole page and stretching outside of it's container. 
you can also specify the margin values explicitly.
i'd also recommend using `max-width` instead as it will improve the resizing on your site when you want to use it on mobile.
another thing, if you want to centre text inside the div you use the `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it width: 70%; and not 50% / 25%?

This is purely the preference of the author. It could be any width, or max-width.

The important thing is that it is not `100%` or `auto` which would cause the element to fill the entire width and make the idea of centring pointless.

```css
div {
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 1ex auto;
  width: 70%;
}

div+div {
  width: 50%;
}

div+div+div {
  width: 25%;
}

div+div+div+div {
  width: 100px;
}

div+div+div+div+div {
  max-width: 80ex;
}

div+div+div+div+div {
  max-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```